# Hosting Angular app with CloudFront and S3 under "subdirectory"

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I've been trying to solve an issue for a few days and I don't know what to do anymore.

I have an Angular SPA hosted using CloudFront and S3, which works perfectly fine without any problems. Now there is a need to create a specific URL pointing to another SPA application, which will be in another S3 bucket.

Example:

https://www.mywebsite.com/ <- main SPA application
https://www.mywebsite.com/checkout <- another SPA application

What I did was create a new Origin in CloudFront pointing to the new S3 bucket, create a behavior that matches /checkout* looking in the new bucket for the application for this URL.

This is not working. When I access the /checkout URL, something redirects back to / of the main URL. Has anyone had experience with this scenario?

What I did was create a new Origin in CloudFront pointing to the new S3 bucket, create a behavior that matches /checkout* looking in the new bucket for the application for this URL.

Comment: Whats the order of behaviour ?You should have /checkout* first and then Default(*) as cloudfront will execute behaviours in order they are defined

Comment: The "/checkout*" is in front of "Default(*)".